# SSIS SQL Execute Task storing in variable

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, transformation

I'm trying to store newest date in variable using SSIS. I have this code in a SQL query:

```
select max(\[update_date\]) as newestdate 
from \[Sheet1$\]
```

Result set is single row and my variable name is `user::newdate`.

I get this error:

> Unsupported data type on result set binding newestdate

In Excel my update date is like 1/1/2022, 2/2/2022 and so on.

And my variable newdate is of type `datetime`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it considers update_date field as varchar (is it VARCHAR in your Sheet1$ table?) and returns varchar as well.

Try to convert it:

```
select max(CAST([update_date] AS DATETIME)) as newestdate from [Sheet1$]
```

Or better load it to Sheet1$ as DATETIME, specifying it when you import data from Excel.